# The new Ubuntu upgrade (13.04) wont let me connect to wi-fi

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, 13.04

Ever since I upgraded Ubuntu to 13.04 I haven't been able to connect to any wi-fi. I could connect to wi-fi with every version of Ubuntu till this one. When I click on network manager the "Enable Wireless" appears faded, I cant click on it. I suspect it could be driver issues... My network card is: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter

Anyone have any clues on how to fix?

PS: I've been seeing a lot of wireless network issues ever since the new version came out.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me with my thinkpad t420

Install Broadcom b43 and b43-legacy wireless driver in Ubuntu 13.04 / 12.10 / 12.04
http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-broadcom-b43-legacy-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Comment: Hey guys, I found the solution. Strangely it lets me connect to wireless internet if I lock the laptop (Close the screen) and unlock it again. After that it allows me to connect to wi-fi. I have no idea why is it like this but I finally can use my internet again. Thanx for all the help do. I highly appreciate it :)